# Accessing the UTF-8 Cuneiform Numbers and Punctuation Symbols

Tags: bash, unicode

Does anybody know how to access the UTF-8 Cuneiform Numbers and Punctuation Symbols?

```
  twash="\u12400"       # two ash
  thash="\u12401"       # three ash
  frash="\u12402"       # four ash
  fvash="\u12403"       # five ash
  sxash="\u12404"       # six ash
  svash="\u12405"       # seven ash
  eiash="\u12406"       # eight ash
  niash="\u12407"       # nine ash
  thdsh="\u12408"       # three dish
  frdsh="\u12409"       # four dish
  fvdsh="\u1240a"       # five dish
  sxdsh="\u1240b"       # six dish
  svdsh="\u1240c"       # seven dish
  eidsh="\u1240d"       # eight dish
  nidsh="\u1240e"       # nine dish
  fru="\u1240f"         # four u
```

The following did net got me the correct numeric symbols.

```
  echo ""
  echo "> cunif-numpc-utf-scout"

  echo -e "twash: $twash" "| thash: $thash" "| frash: $frash" "|" \
          "fvash: $fvash"

  echo -e "sxash: $sxash" "| svash: $svash" "| eiash: $eiash" "|" \
          "niash: $niash"

  echo -e "thdsh: $thdsh" "| frdsh: $frdsh" "| fvdsh: $fvdsh" "|" \
          "sxdsh: $sxdsh"

  echo -e "svdsh: $svdsh" "| eidsh: $eidsh" "| nidsh: $nidsh" "|" \
          "fru: $fru"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `\UHHHHH`, not `\uHHHHH`. The lower case **u** only allows up to four hex digits as part of the escape sequence. The upper-case **U** allows up to 8.

With that change, you should get

```
> cunif-numpc-utf-scout
twash:  | thash:  | frash:  | fvash: 
sxash:  | svash:  | eiash:  | niash: 
thdsh:  | frdsh:  | fvdsh:  | sxdsh: 
svdsh:  | eidsh:  | nidsh:  | fru:
```

(Depending on your terminal's ability to render those characters, of course)

You can also set your variables directly to those characters without having to rely on `echo` escape sequences, using what `bash` calls *ANSI-C quoting*:

```bsh
twash=$'\U12400'
```

Comment: Got the correct symbols after following your upper-case U.